# EF Core 2.1 - Verify if database exists dont work after update

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, npgsql

This code worked perfectly before update NPGSQL from 2.0 to 2.1

```
public static void EnsurePopulated(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    CoreDatabaseContext context = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<CoreDatabaseContext>();
    bool databaseExists  = (context.Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>() as RelationalDatabaseCreator).Exists();

    //Don't work too
    //bool databaseExists  = context.Database.EnsureCreated(); 
}
```

After update i got the error:

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found:
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.NpgsqlDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseNpgsql(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptionsBuilder,
>   System.String,
>   System.Action`1)'.'

VS2017 15.7.0
.NET 4.7.2
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 2.1
.NET Core 2.1.300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you install the latest 2.1 SDK? How are you running your app? When you run `dotnet --version`, does it display `2.1.300` ? Do you have the latest version of VS 2017 installed?

Those exceptions usually occur when you have a mismatch/incompatible dll versions. If you update everything, clear your bin/obj folder, it should work.

Comment: VS2017 15.7.0
.NET 4.7.2
Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 2.1
.NET Core 2.1.300

Comment: I deleted the folders and recompiled, and the error continues

Comment: you have an old version of VS installed. You need to update it.